# How to use functional programming in C++11 to obtain the keys from a map?

Tags: c++, c++11, functional-programming, key-value, idioms

An `std::map<K,V> m`, in a mathematical view, is a function f<sub>m</sub> in which all pairs of domain and range elements (x,y) ∈ K × V such that f<sub>m</sub>(x) = y.

So, I want to get the domain of f<sub>m</sub>, i.e. the set of all keys (or perhaps the range - the set of all values). I can do this *procedurally* with C++11, like so:

```
std::unordered_set<K> keys;
for (const auto& kv_pair : m) { keys.insert(kv_pair->first); }
```

right? But - I want to do it *functionally* (read: In a fancy way which makes me feel superior). How would I do that?

**Notes:**

- I do not necessarily need the result to be an std::unordered_set; something which would could replace such a set would probably work too (e.g. a set [Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)).
- Readability, (reasonable) terseness and avoiding gratuitous copying of data are all considerations.

Comment: You mean that you want some `fold` operation on `map` ... There is none...

Comment: You put the procedural code inside a function, call it a fancy name, pretend it's a primitive, and feel superior using it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Isn't `std::accumulate` a fold?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Actually, not really. That is, my imperative implementation looks like a fold, but the set is not really a single value. Think of it this way: Suppose instead of `keys` I had a second map, and I'd insert the pair into it. What kind of a fold would it be if it produced its input as output?

Comment: @einpoklum: FWIW, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) discusses identity and list reversal fold operations, implying they don't have to reduce a list to a scalar.  Still, use of the terminology might not be consistent across Comp Sci., particular languages etc..

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, an important characteristic for intuitive functional code is that the algorithm actually return the result, rather than setting some variable elsewhere as a side effect.  This can be done with `std::accumulate`, e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    typedef std::map<int, int> M;

    M m { {1, -1}, {2, -2}, {3, -3}, {4, -4} };

    auto&& x = std::accumulate(std::begin(m), std::end(m), std::set<int>{},
                               [](std::set<int>& s, const M::value_type& e)
                               {
                                  return s.insert(e.first), std::move(s);
                                                // .first is key,
                               });              // .second is value
    for (auto& i : x)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4
```

See it run [here](http://ideone.com/DLPL1K)

The `std::begin(m), std::end(m)` bit is actually a big headache, as it frustrates chaining of such operations.  For example, it's be ideal if we could chain "functional" operations like our "GET KEYS" above alongside others...

```
x = m. GET KEYS . SQUARE THEM ALL . REMOVE THE ODD ONES
```

...or at least...

```
x = f(f(f(m, GET KEYS), SQUARE THEM ALL), REMOVE THE ODD ONES)
```

...but you'll have to write some trivial code yourself to get there or pick up a library supporting functional "style".

Comment: I'd agree that for a true functional style you want to return a value rather than mutate something but the current design of the STL makes this hard to do efficiently unfortunately. Because you take the `set` argument by reference and return by value in your `accumulate` lambda you will probably end up with the `set` getting copied on every call to `accumulate`.

Comment: @mattnewport: if we reason from the "possible implementation" [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate), each binary operator may be invoked akin to `init = op(init, *first);` where `init` is the function's by-value copy of `std::set<int>{}`.  So, I'm ultimately alternating `s.insert()` with `s = s;` - just have to hope the latter's optimised away or at least dealt with quickly.

Comment: Questions: 1. Is there really no version of accumulate which takes a range-ish object rather than a pair of iterators? If not, maybe I should just write one in some general "STL utils" header 2. Can't the the signature of the lambda be automatically inferred somehow?

Comment: @einpoklum 1. no, and yes - feel free to write one. 2. I think that's the best you can do in C++11, but C++14 is introducing automatic deduction of argument types - from memory `[] (auto& s, auto& e) { ... }`... AFAIK you'll still need at least that much to name them and express the intended by-value vs. by-reference semantics....

Comment: @TonyD: So nothing like a λs.λe.insert(s,e) , eh?

Comment: @einpoklum: well, there are 3rd-party libraries around that often use placeholders `_1`, `_2` etc - I suspect you could replace the C++11 lambda with something like `(_1.insert(_2.first), _1)` using [`boost::lambda`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/lambda/using_library.html#lambda.introductory_examples).

Comment: @TonyD: Not just 3rd party; see `std::placeholders::_1`

Comment: @MSalters: such placeholders might have the same identifiers, but AFAIK they have to be used in the context of a `std::bind` invocation and aren't even vaguely analogous to the `boost::lambda` versions.  perhaps `std::bind` could be used but for anything beyond a simple function call I personally prefer the "`[] (...) {...}`" lambda or something like lambda... I'm not even sure how you'd get the equivalent of the comma operator using `bind` without an out-of-line support function, which is pretty inelegant for one-off use.

Comment: @TonyD in general it's unlikely a compiler can optimize away the copy on return from `op` unfortunately: http://ideone.com/nHe3Oq . There's an open issue to look at `std::move()`ing the first argument into `op()` in `std::accumulate()` to address this: http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-closed.html#2055

Comment: @matthnewport I don't think the first argument matters as it can be accepted by reference as my lambda already does.  I achieved a massive speedup and beat the O(n^2) aspect by having the lambda return `move(s)`... see [here](http://ideone.com/hoQG4w) and have a play... without `move` 8000 elements was taking 3.8 seconds, with `move` 1,000,000 takes 0.38 seconds.  Code in answer updated accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

`Boost.Range` provides exactly that, with the adaptor `map_keys`. Look at [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/map_keys.html) example from the documentation.

You can write:

```
auto keys = m | boost::adaptors::map_keys;

// keys is a range view to the keys in your map, no copy involved
// you can use keys.begin() and keys.end() to iterate over it
```

**EDIT** : I'll leave my old answer below, it uses iterators instead of ranges. Notice that 
the range represented by the two `boost::transform_iterator` still represents the set of keys in your map.

IMO the *functional* way to do that would require an iterator that points to the keys of the map, so that you can simply use `std::copy`.
It makes sense because you are not transforming or accumulating anything, you are just *copying* the keys.

Unfortunately the standard does not provide iterator adaptors, but you can use those provided by `Boost.Iterator`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_set>    
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>

struct get_first
{
    template<class A, class B>
    const A & operator()(const std::pair<A,B> & val) const
    {
        return val.first;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::string> m;
    std::unordered_set<int> r;

    // ...

    std::copy(boost::make_transform_iterator(m.begin(), get_first{}),
              boost::make_transform_iterator(m.end(), get_first{}),
              std::inserter(r, r.end()) );
}
```

It would be more expressive to have an iterator that dereferences the `Kth` element of  a tuple/pair, but `transform_iterator` will do the job fine.

Comment: Nobody said I have to copy the keys. I could simply provide a facade set which looks through the map's keys when you try to access element.

Comment: @einpoklum I see. `Boost.Range` has the functionality to do exactly that, I'll complete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of ways you could write this. One slightly more 'functional' way is:

```
vector<string> keys;
transform(begin(m), end(m), back_inserter(keys), [](const auto& p){ return p.first; });
```

But to really improve on this and enable a more functional style using the standard library we need something like Eric Niebler's [Range Proposal](https://ericniebler.github.io/std/wg21/D4128.html) to be standardized. In the meantime, there are a number of non-standard range based libraries like Eric's [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) and [boost Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) you can use to get a more functional style.

Comment: ... and there's no variant of transform() which takes a range (i.e. an object with `begin()` and `end()` methods) rather than a pair of iterators? Also, I would rather not have to declare keys...

Comment: Updated with some info about range based libraries.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::map<int, int> m;
std::unordered_set<int> keys;

std::for_each(m.begin(), m.end(), [&keys](decltype(*m.begin()) kv)-> void {keys.insert(kv.first);});
```